# Can't move cursor in UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit

I have a fairly bog-standard UI with a text field embedded in a few subviews. I'm seeing an issue where I can't move the cursor once I've typed in the text field, it continually just moves back to the start of the input.

At no point anywhere in the code are any methods called to change the editing position, like `setSelectedTextRange` or similar.

Please excuse the Objective-C, this is a legacy codebase!

```
self.textField = [UITextField new];
self.textField.text = element.value;
self.textField.placeholder = element.placeholder;
self.textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
self.textField.delegate = self;
self.textField.autocorrectionType = element.autocorrectionType;
self.textField.autocapitalizationType = element.autocapitalizationType;
self.textField.secureTextEntry = element.secureTextEntry;
self.textField.keyboardType = element.keyboardType;
[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTextChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[self addSubview:self.textField];
```

```
- (void)handleTextChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
    self.inputElement.value = sender.text;

    // If we're showing the validation warning, give real time feedback to user
    if (self.isShowingValidationWarning) {
        [self validate];
    }
}

- (void)validate
{
    BOOL isValid = self.inputElement.isValid;

    [self showValidationHint:!isValid animated:YES];
}

- (void)showValidationHint:(BOOL)show animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.isShowingValidationWarning = show;

    CGFloat duration = 0.0;

    if (animated) {
        duration = 0.2;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

        if (show) {

            self.characterCountLabel.alpha = 0.0;
            self.validationButton.alpha = 1.0;
            self.validationButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        } else {

            self.characterCountLabel.alpha = 1.0;
            self.validationButton.alpha = 0.0;
            self.validationButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
        }
    }];
}
```

`inputElement.value` doesn't have a setter or getter function, so nothing funky going on there!

Comment: post handleTextChange() method code.

Comment: Done, Although I've commented out all of the code from it to make sure it's nothing in there!

Comment: I had a similar issue but we use Swift. For me I found out that the problem was that we were calling `becomeFirstResponder` in the "wrong" event (`viewWillAppear`), I moved it to `viewDidAppear` and the issue is gone. I can't see in the code that you posted if you are calling `becomeFirstResponder` but I'm not familiar with objc and if the function is called the same

Comment: @juanreyesv hey, thanks for the solution! Do you know where you found the answer for that originally?

Comment: Hey @inokey no worries, happy this helped. I found the solution on my own trying out a few things until it was fixed

Comment: @juanreyesv got it. Well! Great find. I couldn't spot this one since we have two cases: one with `UITexField` and one with `UITextView`. The thing is that `UITextView` implementation does not reproduce the bug! Only `UITextField` was affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here was exactly what @juanreyesv pointed out in the comments! `becomeFirstResponder` call was moved to `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewWillAppear` and now it's working!